# Is there a way to inject pipes in HTML dynamically? Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

**The subject**
I'm building an abstract table component to which I pass what pipe it should use in certain columns. As the data passed may vary, so the pipes should vary as well.

**The goal**
To use whatever pipe is passed to the table

**The project**
Here's how it should look like in html in my opinion

```html
<!-- html --> 

<span *ngIf="element.pipe">{{ row[element.column] | <<here_inject_an_appropriate_pipe>> }}</span>
```

The column settings are passed through an object and have form of

```js
//typescript  

columnSettings: [
    ...
    {column: 'fruitExpDate', caption: 'Best before', pipe: 'date: \"' + PIPE_DATE_FORMAT + '\"' },
    ...
]
```

and `PIPE_DATE_FORMAT` holds the string `'yyyy-MM-dd'`

**What I tried**

1. Passing the pipe directly through a variable like

```html
<!-- html --> 

<span *ngIf="element.pipe">{{ row[element.column] | element.pipe }}</span>
```

2. Creating custom pipe which takes another pipe as an argument

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'dynamicPipe',
})
export class DynamicPipe implements PipeTransform {
    // constructor(private abstractTableService: AbstractTableService) {}

    transform(value: any, pipe: string): any {
        const pipeToken: any = pipe.split(':')[0].replace(/[\s]+/g, '');
        const pipeArgs: any = pipe.split(':')[1].replace(/[\s]+/g, '');

        console.log(value);
        console.log(pipe);

        // return pipeToken.transform(value, ...pipeArgs);
        return 'check pipe';
    }
}
```

and here I tried many different things to call the requested pipe but eventually didn't figure out how to do this. Here's my html with the custom pipe:

```html
<!-- html --> 

<span *ngIf="element.pipe">{{ row[element.column] | dynamicPipe: element.pipe }}</span>
```

3. Creating a custom service to call imported pipes

```js
@Injectable()
export class AbstractTableService {
    constructor(
        private date: DatePipe,
    ) {}

    getDatePipe(): DatePipe {
        return this.date;
    }
}
```

but here I had no idea how to use this service effectively.

Comment: Try like that
<span *ngIf="element.pipe">{{ row[element.column] | element.pipe }}</span>

Comment: `Parser Error: Unexpected token '.' at column 31 in [{{ row[element.column] | element.pipe }}]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the selected pipe inside a dynamic pipe. To do that, you can utilize Angular injector. The dynamic pipe (what I call it) can be something like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injector, Type } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dynamicPipe'
})
export class DynamicPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  transform(value: any, requiredPipe: Type<any>, pipeArgs: any): any {
    const injector = Injector.create({
      name: 'DynamicPipe',
      parent: this.injector,
      providers: [
        { provide: requiredPipe }
      ]
    })
    const pipe = injector.get(requiredPipe)
    return pipe.transform(value, pipeArgs);
  }

}
```

Make sure to pass the pipe class (type) as args not a string representation of its name. If you are going to pass a string, let's say the data comes from server-side, you might need to consider creating a mapping for that.

A fully working example can be found here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evzwnh

This is a rough implementation. I am not sure about Tree-Shaking. It needs more testing and optimization.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Can you tell me one more thing - how do I pass and later handle pipe argument like for example the format string in case of DatePipe? With `providers: [{provide: args, useClass: args, useValue: pipeArgs}],` or somehow else?

Comment: I have updated the answer and stackblitz to include pipeArgs. You only need to pass a the args to the dynamicPipe. Simply, we pass those args along with the value `transform(value, pipeArgs)`.

Answer (score 1):

pipe is NOT a string, so you can't use `pipe:'date: \"' + PIPE_DATE_FORMAT + '\"'`

Your second aproach is closed to you want get it, but you need use a switch case

NOTE 1: From Angular 9 you can use directly the functions: formatDate, formatNumber, formatCurrency and formatPercent

```
import { formatDate,formatNumber,formatCurrency,formatPercent } from '@angular/common';


transform(value: any, pipe: string): any {
    const pipeToken: any = pipe.split(':')[0].replace(/[\s]+/g, '');
    const pipeArgs: any = pipe.split(':')[1].replace(/[\s]+/g, '');
    let result=value;
    switch (pipeToken)
    {
       case "date":
         result=formatDate(value,pipeArgs) //(*)
         break
       case "number"
         result=formatNumber(value,pipeArgs) //(*)
         break
       ...
    }
    return result;
}
```

(*) check the docs to know how use the functions, I write "pseudo-code"

NOTE 2: perhafs if you create your "columns objects" with two properties, pipeKing and args- this one as an array-, your pipe becomes more confortable

e.g.

```
  {
   column: 'fruitExpDate', 
   caption: 'Best before', 
   pipeKind: 'date'
   pipeArgs:[PIPE_DATE_FORMAT]
  }
```

Comment: That sounds good. But I wonder if you know about any way to call a specific pipe in ts file by its name just like we do this in html?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

export type OmitFirstArg<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [unknown, ...infer U] ? U : never;

@Pipe({
  name: 'dynamicPipe',
  pure: true
})
export class DynamicPipe<P extends PipeTransform> implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(
    value: Parameters<P['transform']>[1],
    pipeTransform: P,
    pipeArgs?: OmitFirstArg<Parameters<P['transform']>>): ReturnType<P['transform']> | unknown {
    if (!('transform' in pipeTransform)) {
      return value;
    }
    return pipeTransform.transform(value, ...(pipeArgs || []));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Should it be `value: Parameters<P['transform']>[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your original model and separate the pipe type and the pipe parameters. It would help a lot, let's say, you have this:

```js
columnSettings: [
    ...
    {
      column: 'fruitExpDate', 
      caption: 'Best before', 
      pipeType: 'date', 
      pipeParams: PIPE_DATE_FORMAT 
    },
    ...
]
```

Then you could write your 'dynamic pipe' logic in the html, and using existing pipes directly:

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="element.pipeType">
   <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'date'">{{ row[element.column] | date:element.pipeParams }}</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'...'">...</ng-container>
   <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-element>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

For conditional piping you can map those items and transform accordingly.

```
columnSettings: [
...
 {
   column: 'fruitExpDate', 
   caption: 'Best before', 
   pipeType: 'date', 
   pipeParams: PIPE_DATE_FORMAT 
 },
 ...
]


columnSettings = columnSettings.map((col) => {
   if(col.pipeType === 'date) {
      col.pipeVal = (new DatePipe).transform(col) // or whatever you want to pass
   } else if(col.pipeType === 'blah) {
      col.pipeVal = (new BlahPipe).transform(col) // or whatever you want to pass
   }
  return col;
})
```

Now in the template you won't need any conditional statement but rather just print `col.pipeVal`